# Creating custom screen under Privacy settings of Windows

Tags: windows, desktop-application, desktop, windows-10-desktop

I want to create custom screen under Privacy settings on Windows. It should look something like the following:
[image]

I have no clue how to achieve this. Please assist.

Comment: Are you developing Universal Window Platform app? It seems you want to change the system Settings app to add a Custom Privacy Screen item? You can not achieve it in UWP app.

Comment: As of now, I have not decided the approach because first I have to find out the different options to achieve this. This screen should come under PC Settings ->Privacy.

Comment: That page is not extensible. You can add a Privacy section to your app.